# How do I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?

Tags: factor-analysis, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

I'm having a little trouble finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this covariance matrix I have:
$$
 \mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'a + \mathbf{R}.
$$
$\mathbf{R}$ is diagonal, $\mathbf{B}$ is some low-rank matrix, and $a$ is a positive real number.

This is as far as I got. In the case that $\mathbf{B}$ is a column vector, we can use the Matrix Determinant Lemma to simplify the characteristic polynomial:
\begin{align*}
0 &= \det\left(a \mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}' + \mathbf{R} - \lambda I \right)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n(R_{ii} - \lambda)\left( 1 + a\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{B_i^2}{R_{ii}-\lambda}  \right)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n(R_{ii} - \lambda)\left(\frac{ \prod_{i=1}^n(R_{ii}-\lambda) + a\sum_{i=1}^nB_i^2\prod_{j\neq i}(R_{jj} - \lambda)  }{ \prod_{i=1}^n(R_{ii}-\lambda) } \right) \\
&=  \prod_{i=1}^n(R_{ii}-\lambda) + a\sum_{i=1}^nB_i^2\prod_{j\neq i}(R_{jj} - \lambda).
\end{align*}

I was thinking a lot of the eigenvalues would be something close to the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{R}$ because
$$
\left[\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'a + \mathbf{R}\right]\left[\mathbf{I} - \frac{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'}{\mathbf{B}'\mathbf{B}}\right] = \mathbf{R}\left[\mathbf{I} - \frac{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'}{\mathbf{B}'\mathbf{B}}\right] ,
$$
but $\mathbf{R}\left[\mathbf{I} - \frac{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'}{\mathbf{B}'\mathbf{B}}\right] \neq \left[\mathbf{I} - \frac{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'}{\mathbf{B}'\mathbf{B}}\right]\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{I} - \frac{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}'}{\mathbf{B}'\mathbf{B}}$ isn't even full rank.

Comment: It's unclear what would constitute "finding" the eigensystem, especially since you're vague about what $B$ is.  You cannot reasonably hope for an effective formula when the question is stated in such generality.  Perhaps something like [Weyl's Inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_in_matrix_theory) will help you establish useful bounds.